# Multiple loading using APP_INITIALIZER?

Tags: angular

I've implemented APP_INITIALIZER correctly i.e for countries objects but I have many other lists of objects and I don't want to add multiple rows in the app.module.ts provider section.

**app module relevant part**

```
 providers: [
        AppLoadService,
        { 
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (appLoadService: AppLoadService) =>
            () => appLoadService.initializeApp(),
            deps: [AppLoadService],
            multi: true
         },
```

**AppLoadService**

```
 public countries: Country[]  = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

initializeApp(): Promise<Country[]> {
  return this.http.get<Country[]>(`${this.url}`)
  .do(result => {
    this.countries = result;
  }).toPromise();
}


getCountries(): Country[] {
  return this.countries;
}
```

I've tried to make initializeApp to return dummy Promise (and added more initMethods) but that stopped from the countries to load to cache.

**If I change the initializeApp to:**

```
initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log(`initializeApp:: inside promise`);
           this.initApplicationLists();
          resolve();
        });
  }
```

And inside initApplicationLists I'm intialize the countries list and others, 
the whole logic stopped working.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you are asking?  Also show what you tried and explain the issue you came across

Comment: I've added more details to question.